# Why message is sent to all rooms even after the client leave the room ad join another room? flask socketio

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

When the client leaves the current room and joins another room, his messages still sent to the old room, how can I make his message just appear for the current room?
the leave_room and join_room are working good because it notifies the user when he joins a room and notifies users in other room that he left the room, so why the message is sent to all the room?

Server-side code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, redirect, url_for, escape, request, flash
from flask_session import Session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send, join_room, leave_room
from time import localtime, strftime




app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

ROOMS = ["General", "Testing", "One More"]

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", rooms=ROOMS)



@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):

    # print(f"\n\n{data}\n\n")
    send({'msg': data['msg'], 'username': data['username'], 'time_stamp': strftime('%b-%d %I:%M%p', localtime()), 'room': data['room']}, broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    join_room(room)
    send({'msg': username + " has joined the " + room + " room."}, room=data['room'])


@socketio.on('leave')
def on_leave(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    leave_room(room)
    send({'msg': username + " has left the " + room + " room."}, room=data['room'])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

client side

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
    let active_room = "General";
    joinRoom(active_room);

    if (!username) {
        username = prompt("Please enter username");
        localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    }
    if (username) {
        document.querySelector('#name-of-client').innerHTML = username;
    }

    // send message to the server
    document.querySelector('#send-btn').onclick = () => {
        socket.send({
            'msg': document.querySelector('#input-msg').value,
            'username': username,
            'room': active_room
        });
        document.querySelector('#input-msg').value = '';
    };

    socket.on('message', data => {

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const span_username = document.createElement('span');
        const span_timestamp = document.createElement('span');
        const br = document.createElement('br');

        if (data.username) {
            span_username.innerHTML = data.username;
            span_timestamp.innerHTML = data.time_stamp;
            p.innerHTML = span_username.outerHTML + br.outerHTML + data.msg + br.outerHTML + span_timestamp.outerHTML + br.outerHTML;
            document.querySelector('#display-msg').append(p);
        } else {
            printSysMsg(data.msg)
        }


    });


    // room selection
    document.querySelectorAll('.select-room').forEach(p => {
        p.onclick = () => {
            let newRoom = p.innerHTML;
            if (newRoom === active_room) {
                msg = `You are alread in the ${active_room} room.`;
                printSysMsg(msg);
            } else {
                leaveRoom(active_room);
                joinRoom(newRoom);
                active_room = newRoom;
            }

        };
    });

    // Leave Rooms
    function leaveRoom(room) {
        socket.emit('leave', {
            'username': username,
            'room': room
        });
    }


    // Join Room
    function joinRoom(room) {

        socket.emit('join', {
            'username': username,
            'room': room
        });

        // Clear Messages
        document.querySelector('#display-msg').innerHTML = "";
    }


    function printSysMsg(msg) {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = msg;
        document.querySelector('#display-msg').append(p);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are creating a chat app using [Sandeep Sudhakaran's YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQDzNNt6xd4) (I guessed it from the `printSysMsg()` function).

### Your problem

I took a look at your code and found that you used `broadcast=True` on the following socket event (`"message"`):

```
@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):

    # print(f"\n\n{data}\n\n")
    send({'msg': data['msg'], 'username': data['username'], 'time_stamp': strftime('%b-%d %I:%M%p', localtime()), 'room': data['room']}, broadcast=True)
```

### Solution

Instead of broadcasting your message event, try limit it to the room:

```
send({'msg': data['msg'], 'username': data['username'], 'time_stamp': strftime('%b-%d %I:%M%p', localtime()), 'room': data['room']}, room=data["room"])
```

### Reasoning

Remember on the official [Flask-SocketIO documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that:

> When a message is sent with the broadcast option enabled, all clients
>   connected to the namespace receive it, including the sender.

I read up the concept of namespace and room on [Socket.IO documentation](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/):

> Within each namespace, you can also define arbitrary channels that
>   sockets can join and leave.

I assume Flask SocketIO works similarly in concept to Socket.IO. So, since you did not specify a specific namespace for this message event, setting `broadcast=True` means that "a default global namespace with the name '/' is used," and your messages are sent to everyone in this namespace.

*I could be wrong as I just started learning about this 3 days ago*, but this means that your broadcasting includes all the rooms that you've created in the namespace '/'. Therefore, `join_room` and `leave_room` will not help as all the rooms are still under the same namespace. All of them will receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

In your .js file, you have:

```
let active_room = "General";
joinRoom(active_room);
```

right at the top of the file.  Your user will be kicked back to "General" every time. Try putting some print statements on your server side and console.log statements on your client side to double check what room you're in.